# jQuery: creating a custom event 

Tags: jquery

I'm supposed to create a custom event triggered on page load that adds a class 'green' to the div with the id #myElementId.  This is my attempt at the code but I'm getting an error message saying that I have to add the class green. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#myElementId').bind('ready', function() {
      $(this).addClass('green');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="myElementId"></div>

</body>
```

Update

This is taken from a codecademy lesson that's supposed to teach me how to create a custom event that adds a class on page load, so even though there are other simpler solutions, I'm trying to solve it the way the lesson intended.

this is the hint they gave

```
$("#myElementId").on("myCustomEvent", function(event) {
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure `div`s don't have `onready` events.

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: It's through a codecademy exercise, custom error message. Oops, try again. 
You need to give the div the class '.green'

Comment: Why do you want to use an event instead of just `$('#myElementID').addClass('green')`?

Comment: @bfavaretto see update in the OP

Comment: @Michael ok, so here is another hint: `.trigger`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myElementId").addClass('green');
}​);​
```

Also note that you have typo in your `id`. It's `myElementId`, not `myElementID`.

**EDIT**: To trigger an event, use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Bind a function to be executed when 'myCustomEvent' is triggered
 $('#myElementId').bind('myCustomEvent', function() {
   $(this).addClass('green');
 });

 // Trigger the event 'myCustomEvent'
 $('#myElementId').trigger("myCustomEvent"); 

});​
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.7, you should use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/E7zyW/)**.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the typo. However, the point of the exercise is to create a custom event that adds a class 'green' on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class by name green in the CSS .. That should get the work done for you..

```
.green
{
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mD88R/)

Also you do not need this line

```
$('#myElementID').bind('ready', function() {
```